# Rust vector type conversion / interface issue between Itertools and function with slice indexing

Tags: vector, rust, slice, rust-itertools

**Aim:** generate permutations and index into each one in parallel.

**Attempt:** use `Itertools` to assign all permutations to a resulting vector and then use `rayon` to process each one.

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;
use rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u128> = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].to_vec();
    let k = 4;

    let vector = data.into_iter().permutations(k).map_into::<Vec<u128>> 
    ().collect_vec();

    (vector).into_par_iter().for_each(move |x| index_vec(x));

}

fn index_vec(i: Vec<u128>) -> () {
    let mut colour_code: String = String::from("");
    let mut index_position = 0;

    for _ in 0..4 {
        colour_code.push_str(COLOURS[i[index_position]]);
        colour_code.push(' ');
        index_position += 1;
    }
    println!("Colour code: {}", colour_code);
}

const COLOURS: [&str; 7] = [
    "red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "grey", "orange",
];
```

**Error:** slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`

However, if I change all vectors to type `usize`, then Itertools throws an error on the `map_into` method: the trait `From<Vec<u128>>` is not implemented for `Vec<usize>`.

How can I make Itertools and slice indices cooperate?

Comment: [The code you've given, with imports added, compiles and runs without error.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=caa1a983282937039a01fd6110ff1551) Could you check that you posted the version you intended to ask about?

Comment: Thanks @kevin-reid - I had simplified my code too much for this post. I have updated it now. It seems the error appears when trying to index to create a string. For each permutation I want to create a string with the words (colours) in the order of that permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the posted code compile and run all you need to do is convert from the `u128` to a `usize`, which is used for indexing the array.

I would consider this "safe" currently, as there are no systems with pointer sizes > 128 bytes, that I know of. However beware, that this conversion can [fail in theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832438/why-is-rusts-usize-to-u128-conversion-considered-failable)

So the fixed code would look like that:

```rust
use rayon::iter::ParallelIterator;
use rayon::iter::IntoParallelIterator;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let data: Vec<u128> = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].to_vec();
    let k = 4;

    let vector = data.into_iter().permutations(k).map_into::<Vec<u128>> 
    ().collect_vec();

    (vector).into_par_iter().for_each(move |x| index_vec(x));

}

fn index_vec(i: Vec<u128>) -> () {
    let mut colour_code: String = String::from("");
    let mut index_position = 0;

    for _ in 0..4 {
        colour_code.push_str(COLOURS[i[index_position] as usize]);
        colour_code.push(' ');
        index_position += 1;
    }
    println!("Colour code: {}", colour_code);
}

const COLOURS: [&str; 7] = [
    "red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "pink", "grey", "orange",
];
```

Playground link is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f4cf880ad6885f6cca2b463e3089658e).

Comment: Many thanks frankenapps for this simple but powerful fix! Answer delightfully accepted. And thank you @peter-reid for nudging me to expound on my query.